# Spring Cloud Data Flow with S3 as artifact repo

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, pcf

Is it possible to configure spring cloud data flow to download the artifacts from an S3 storage bucket like ECSS3 as against maven repository ?

Due to corporate security reasons we can't download artifacts dynamically from internal maven repository in production.
We are looking into an approach where the artifacts will be deployed under a bucket name in ECS (/release-artifacts) and SCDF pulling the artifacts from S3.

If this can be done

1. How do you configure SCDF for ECSS3 store ?
   (https://.) - not sure how to send access key and pwd
2. How to register tasks accordingly

SCDF docs mention the task registration can use artifacts from maven, http or file - If I have rest end point that can serve the artifacts (backed by ECS-S3) would that work ?
I don't see any examples on registration or SCDF env configuration to use http

Thanks-